# Missing pyrsa-encrypt.exe file - how to resolve?

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

Working with a colleague in setting up their work environment using python (> 3.9) and some packages (dbt for bigquery).

We've successfully setup their virtual environment, but for some odd reason they are missing pyrsa-encrypt.exe which is required for these other packages. Weirdly enough, the decrypt version of that file exists (pyrsa-decrypt.exe).

I tried googling the issue and came across a few packages that install pyrsa or specifically the encrypt file but it feels like a shady and dangerous workaround.

Any idea what we can do? Would we need to completely uninstall python from the machine and start the process back over?

Comment: The scripts you listed (and [some other](https://stuvel.eu/python-rsa-doc/cli.html)) are part of package [rsa](https://pypi.org/project/rsa/). You cannot get to them without installing the package (directly or indirectly, as a dependency) using `pip install rsa`